# Return value from function whilst using setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to have a function run with a setTimeout and also return a value assigned to a variable?

An example of what I mean is like this:

```
function count(start, target) {
  if (start < target) {
    start += 0.1;
    return start;
  } else if (start > target) {
    return target;
  }
  // i'm fully aware the return above will prevent this line occur
  // this is my issue currently
  setTimeout(function () {
    count(start, target)
  }, 1000);
}

var el = document.getElementById('test');
var value = count(0.0, 1.0); //get the opacity value

function check() {
  el.style.opacity = value; //assign what the value is in this moment
  if (value != 1.0) {
    setTimeout(check, 0);
  }
}

check();
```

I know this code won't work the way i want it because `return` exit's the function, I wrote it to explain what I am trying to do.

The reason I want to do this in this kinda way is because I have an element which i want to fade in by altering it's opacity.

So i have a function which would increment a start value to a target value using what ever easing i want, this then returns said value which would be assigned to the element's opacity property.

I don't want to pass the element to this `count` function because that means it limits the use of it for when i want to animate other things besides elements.

What would the solution to this problem be?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e8qbohb9/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny so i just have to put the return after the next call for the function ?

Comment: Yes... I think there is a bug in the previous entry https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e8qbohb9/3/

Comment: What? Keep in mind that in your example the function that executes the `setTimeout` returns immediately after, and the only one that has the chance to get the returned value of `count` is the anonymous function you submit to `setTimeout`. From there, there is no way to send back a value by means of the `return` statement, but you can rely on a closure or a callback to actually put it somewhere and thus use it. That said, `value` will receive the result of the first execution of `count` and no others. Is it your purpose to periodically update `value`? If yes, I'll put a response below.

Comment: @skypjack yes that was the idea, value increases and i can call upon it when i needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to call the `count` method again if the value passed for `start` and `target` are not the same if so

```
function count(start, target) {
    var ret;

    if (start < target) {
        ret = start + 0.1;
    } else if (start > target) {
        ret = target;
    }

    if (start != target) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            count(ret, target)
        }, 1000);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/fj8wz052/ but for me with console.log the value does not increase?

Comment: @Dave https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e8qbohb9/5/ - if you want to have a callback then the way to do it is slightly different